# Excel Sheet Value compare and return

Tags: vba, excel

My Requirement is to Compare the Text in each column of a row to match a "constant", if matched return the value of the Next Cell to the "constant".

The above equation has to run against a unique. Eg :

```
Sheet 1                 

T1      abc.ad   test   NOP 
T2          abc.ad  Ext NOP
T3  abc.ad  tst NOP
```

Sheet 2 (Desired Result )

```
T1  abc.ad  test NOP        
T2  abc.ad  Ext  NOP        
T3  abc.ad  Tst  NOP
```

T1,T2,T3 are unique Values. abc.ad is the constanct, we need the values test,ext,Tst in sheet two.

The values of the cells are grouped but not is sorted in same column.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you are after the formula

```
=vlookup(valueToLookFor, RangeToSearch, ColumnInRangeToReturn, exactMatch[true/false])
```

e.g.

```
=vlookup(a1, sheet2!A:C, 3, FALSE)
```

This would compare the value in A1 of the current sheet to the first column in the range Sheet2 columns A to C (3 columns) and return the third column. Using exact match.

Comment: Thank you, but Vlookup wouldn't work since the data in sheet one is not sorted by Column.

Comment: How is it sorted then? How many columns wide can the data be?
If I'm understanding correctly you want to search every column in a sheet for the value and when you find the value you want to return the column 2 columns to the right? If so you're either going to need to write a vba function to do this or perhaps it might be able to use some kind of array formula, but I don't have the time to see if that is possible for you right now.